# SQL Sum boolean values and add summarise row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables, need to get one with summary for the category. Also need to add a summary row.

The main problem is I don`t know how to work with BOOLEAN type.
Tried use 
`SUM(CASE WHEN was_showed = 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` but when I tried it just for table1 it returned "3" in every cases...when exactly it should be "6"

The first table1

```
id  was_showed
1   FALSE
2   TRUE
3   TRUE
4   TRUE
5   TRUE
6   FALSE
7   TRUE
8   TRUE
9   TRUE
```

the second table2

```
id  category
1   test1
2   test2
3   test1
4   test1
5   (null)
6   (null)
7   test1
8   test2
9   test2
```

the third table3

```
id  was_bought
2   TRUE
4   TRUE
5   TRUE
7   TRUE
```

The result I want to get by categories:

```
category | sum(was_showed) | sum(was_bougth)/sum(was_showed)
test1    |   3             |     2/3                 
test2    |   2             |     1/3
NULL     |   1             |      1
```

last row should be:

`all  | sum(was_showed) by all rows | sum(was_bougth)/sum(was_showed) by all rows`

UPDATE: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae8677)

Comment: @GordonLinoff i create it in SQL Fiddle, it works with boolean type...

Comment: @GordonLinoff I`ve read that the BOOLEAN and BOOL are equivalents of TINYINT(1)

Comment: Where's the fiddle?

Comment: @TheImpaler Thought it`s not permitted. Sure http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae8677

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are `tinyint`s you can just add them up.  Getting the total requires some trickery:

```
select coalesce(x.category, c.category) as category,
       sum(s.was_showed) as shown,
       sum(b.was_bought) as was_bought,
       sum(b.was_bought) / sum(s.was_showed) 
from table2 c left join-- categories
     table1 s
     on s.id = c.id left join -- shown (showed?)
     table3 b
     on b.id = c.id cross join
     (select null as category union all
      select 'total' as category
     ) x
group by coalesce(x.category, c.category)
order by (x.category is null) desc, c.category;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae8677/10) is a SQL Fiddle.

Or you can use `with rollup`:

```
select c.category,
       sum(s.was_showed) as shown,
       sum(b.was_bought) as was_bought,
       sum(b.was_bought) / sum(s.was_showed) 
from table2 c left join-- categories
     table1 s
     on s.id = c.id left join -- shown (showed?)
     table3 b
     on b.id = c.id 
group by c.category with rollup;
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae8677/11) for this.

Comment: Thanks, with rollup unfortunately the total is also null. But i`m grateful for the first one!

Answer (score 1):

The query you probably need is:

```
select
  *, 
  1.0 * bought / shown
from (
  select
    c.category,
    sum(case when s.was_showed = 1 then 1 end) as shown,
    sum(case when b.was_bought = 1 then 1 end) as bought
  from adShowCategoryTable c -- categories
  left join adShowsTable s on s.id = c.id -- shown (showed?)
  left join adClicksTable b on b.id = c.id -- bought
  group by c.category
) x
order by category
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88cbe0/10)

Comment: Oh, key is pretty simple, that I should use "1" instead of  "TRUE"... Thanks so much, you save my evening

Comment: Why use `SUM` when you could filter for the records that are true and just `COUNT` them?

Comment: @Hytpo MySQL does not have a true boolean type. It's just a synonym of the numeric type `TINYINT` (a byte).